# Where to put Delegates in .Net Solution

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, namespace-organisation

I have a C# .Net collection of solutions which started as a proof of concept, and has grown to almost 15 different projects. I am currently in the process of rewriting the whole product family, and trying to maintain best practices to the best of my abilities, with future-proof organisation.

I have done some research, and I am still unclear on the best place to keep delegates in a multi-project product to minimise the likelihood of a need for refactoring in the future.

I would assume the general consensus is that you place them anywhere that makes sense for the use case, but in general I feel there is a best way to structure everything in a solution to minimise problems, promote positive modularity, and ease maintenance.

In many cases it is recommended that they travel with where they are used; presumably declared in the namespace above the class file, which in my case would translate to my common library with the common interfaces which mandate the events. I currently have delegates in their own file, in a 'delegate' namespace. Is there an oversight I am making by doing so, or am I overcomplicating the use case for delegates - or is this inline with current usage expectations?

I have done the typical searches, but haven't found anything credible nor substantial; however this could be a consequence of poor keyword selection.

Comment: If the project is large, and you want SOLID-type decoupling I would give delegates the same handling as `interfaces`, viz in an independent assembly, such that both the publisher / implementation and subscriber / callback code are both coupled on the delegates assembly (and any types they use), and not directly to eachother. I have to admit nowadays it is more common to see naked `Func` or `Action`s with no explicit delegate type (Similar thinking to Generic IEnumerables and ILists<> etc).

Comment: Thanks StuartLC!. [Func/Action/Predicate/Converter/Comparison](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/741064/Delegates-its-Modern-Flavors-Func-Action-Predicate) are new to me. Thanks for bringing them to my attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would assume the general consensus is that you place them anywhere
>   that makes sense for the use case, but in general I feel there is a
>   best way to structure everything in a solution to minimise problems,
>   promote positive modularity, and ease maintenance.

Well yes, in the general case, you can just put everything wherever you please it. However, the problems start when you're working in a team. In a team, other people have to *understand the structure of the program* to be able to create code effectively. That implies consistency, which is the end goal.

So, it's not just a matter of intuition; in all the companies that I've worked in, I've started by writing a coding standard and aggressively enforcing it everywhere. In this coding standard, I usually put a ton of good/bad practices involving threading, static use, placement of variables / classes, etc.

Iirc this link http://se.inf.ethz.ch/old/teaching/ss2007/251-0290-00/project/CSharpCodingStandards.pdf and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx will give you a head start, although the former is a bit outdated and both don't really answer your question. It might however help with what you're trying to achieve in the long run.

> [...] I currently have delegates in
>   their own file, in a 'delegate' namespace. Is there an oversight I am
>   making by doing so, or am I overcomplicating the use case for
>   delegates - or is this inline with current usage expectations?

A common library with interfaces makes sense. An interface is essentially a contract between 'client' and 'server', which is an important asset for decoupling a piece of software.

You have to realize at this point that the 'interface' part is a *functional* decomposition, not a technical one. In other words: the fact that you need an 'interface' library is a matter of *contract*, not of *technical constructs*. As such, I don't see why you would ever put classes in a 'classes' folder and why you would put delegates in a 'delegates' folder. In short, a 'delegates' folder doesn't make any sense to me. Put the stuff where it belongs.

At this point, you have a decision to make. (1) You can put a delegate in a single file, (2) you can put a delegate in the class file where it's used (I usually use delegates for a single purpose), (3) you can do both depending on single / multi purpose and (4) you can put single-purpose delegates nested within the class. This basically means you're treating a delegate as a function pointer description, and don't see it as a real 'class'.

Looking at functional decomposition, you can argue that a function pointer belongs to a class, just like methods.

So to concluse. Personally I usually go for option (2) or (3) because it's brief, clear and concise, and doesn't have an impact on the amount of 'typing work' like (4) . Picking (1) will probably bloat your application with small files that have little or no purpose, which will confuse other developers.

Comment: Thank you for the input Atlaste! I should probably add that my library which holds the interfaces, really holds all common components of the problem space. Within that, everything is more or less sorted by scope/function, and then for the larger scopes the interfaces/delegates/types/exceptions are currently in their own namespaces. I'm still chasing the 'ultimate solution' dragon and working towards the best implementation before I formalise the release - but there is still much to do. It sounds like I am currently leaning towards points 1 & 2 depending on use.

Comment: @Gui "Sorting" also sounds like you're having very big class/interface files. I usually try to make them small and with limited, well-defined, well-bound functionality. In practice this means that most of my classes have about 100 lines of code; constructor first, then fields, properties, then members (so you can easily spot what data a class holds). Still, the latter is mostly a matter of taste; the key points you should focus on are (1) functional decomposition and (2) relentless standardization.

Comment: @atlaste I do have some pretty monstrous classes/interfaces in my prototype, but in the re-write I am pretty happy with my class/interface sizes in general. I do have a few which are large, but like you, most are 100 lines or less, and well bounded. Thanks again for your answer, I am making good progress tonight!